# Where to write the network call in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-bottomnavigation

I have a `BottomNavigationBar` with 3 tabs. Consider I select a product in an e-commerce app from the pages inside the first `BottomNavigationBarItem`. I need to see that product in the second `BottomNavigationBarItem`(cart page). I have written the network call code in `initState()` of second `BottomNavigationBarItem`; but it will not be called when I go to that page and I can't see the recently added product to the cart. Is it better to write them in the build method itself? Writing them in the build method calls it every time I go to other tabs also.

Comment: You can store the cart items in a cart items list and then load the list in cart page. So in the first navigation, you add items to that list and in the second one, you load items.

Comment: @gegobyte But, it goes into complexity of persisting that list and all... there isn't any other way?

Answer (score 0):

Use [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) or [StreamBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html) to network call and flow the data to UI

Comment: It has the same effect of writing the network call in the build method. Is it possible to call the build() method only when that tab is selected? @KumarSunil17

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _selectedPage = 0;
  String _selectedProduct;

  Widget getCurrentPage(){
    switch(_selectedPage){
      case 0:
        return Page1((selectedProduct){
          setState((){
          this._selectedProduct = selectedProduct;
            _selectedPage=1;
        });});
      case 1:
        return Page2(this._selectedProduct);
      case 2:
        return Page3();
      default:
        return Center(child:Text('Error'));
    }
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(

      body: getCurrentPage(),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        onTap: (index){
          setState((){
            _selectedPage = index;
          });
        },
        currentIndex: _selectedPage,
      items: ['tab 1', 'tab 2', 'tab3'].map((e)=>BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Container(),
      title: Text(e),
      )).toList(),),
    );
  }
}

class Page1 extends StatelessWidget {
  final Function(String) onProductClick;
  const Page1(this.onProductClick);  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title:Text('Page 1')),
      body:Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        RaisedButton(
        child: Text('Product 1'),onPressed: ()=>onProductClick('Product 1'),),
        RaisedButton(
        child: Text('Product 2'),onPressed: ()=>onProductClick('Product 2'),),
        RaisedButton(
        child: Text('Product 3'),onPressed: ()=>onProductClick('Product 3'),),
        RaisedButton(
        child: Text('Product 4'),onPressed: ()=>onProductClick('Product 4'),),
        RaisedButton(
        child: Text('Product 5'),onPressed: ()=>onProductClick('Product 5'),),
      ],)
    );
  }
}
class Page2 extends StatelessWidget {

  final String selectedProduct;
  const Page2(this.selectedProduct);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title:Text('Page 2')),
      body:Center(child:Text(selectedProduct??'Nothing selected')) 
    );
  }
}
class Page3 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title:Text('Page 3')),
      body:Center(child:Text('Page 3'))
    );
  }
}
```